# Nextjs hydration failed

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-i18next

I am using `react-i18next` dependency, and I am having problems with using it with next.js

In my `_app.js` I have:

```
if (!isServer) {
    init_i18n();
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    // this if statement is causing a problem!
    if (i18n.isInitialized) {
        return <Component {...pageProps} />;
    } else {
        return <></>;
    }
}
```

When I had `_app.js` without if statement:

```
if (!isServer) {
    init_i18n();
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

It was giving me other hydration error: `Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "navbar.dashboard" Client: "Dashboard"`

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the exact error message when you are mentioning the if statement ? Can you share the error stack trace for better debugging ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I am getting 2 errors: `Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.` ; `Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.`

Comment: There is a nextJs specific i18n lib, that will take away that heavy lifting for you: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next - surprise: It's based on react-i18next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `react-i18next` I am now using `next-i18next`, and I don't have this issue with hydrating anymore. Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Such hydration issues is because some part of code is trying to use window object which is not available on server. Move such code under componentDidMount Or equivalent in functional component.